# Installation issue (black screen after clicking on "Try or install Ubuntu")

Tags: system-installation, lenovo

so I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my Lenovo Legion 5 computer, and each time I click on the "Try or install Ubuntu" option, I'm getting these lines of errors:

[errors picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZYMm.png)

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug) : Could not resolve symbol [\_SB/PCI0.PB2],
AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)  
ACPI Error : AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/ps object-220)  
ACPI BIOS Error (bug) : Could not resolve symbol [\_SB/PCI0.GP17.VGA.LCD._BCM.AFN7], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
ACPI Error : Aborting method \_SB/PCI0.GP17.VGA.LCD._BCM due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
```

So far I've tried/checked the following things:

- Trying the installation on another computer, and it worked, so I'm guessing that the problem doesn't come neither from the USB and from the iso I downloaded.
- I tried, like many posts said, to disable secure boot mode and to reset setup mode in the BIOS, it did fix some errors that were appearing before, in particular the "Integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65" error. But the installation still leads to a black screen afterwards.
- Apparently sometimes the laptop is too recent for the installation but the latest version came under two weeks ago so I suppose that this is not the cause.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/VV0JC13CH/ff9c19325650b5f88c611653b6d3698e) someone was really busy. As a starter you should add [nomeodeset](http://www.ashwinraon.in/how-to-solve-ubuntu-blank-screen-boot/)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the "Integrity: problem loading X.509 certificate -65" issue while attempting to install Ubuntu 22.04 in my case. After following the exact instructions mentioned in the URL by @kanehekili [here](https://gist.github.com/VV0JC13CH/ff9c19325650b5f88c611653b6d3698e), specifically:

```
Fix "Integrity: problem loading X.509 certificate -65"
1. Go to bios during boot by pressing F2
2: Disable the Secure Boot in bios
3: Reset Setup Mode ( this function is in Bios )
4: Launch Ubuntu
5: Enable the Secure Boot in bios
```

I still had the issue. What solved it next was the following:

- In the grub section, I was selecting "try or install ubuntu", the first option. With that option selected the black screen was still there.
- Selecting the "Ubuntu (graphics)" option, prompted to the install ubuntu menu.

Comment: this answer could be completely unrelated. insufficient information in question.

Comment: This question is too vague for the answer.